# Writing callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery to write things like this:

```
    $('#current_image').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#current_image').attr('src',newImage).show();
    });
```

This is lovely, once the `fadeOut` has completed, the nested bit executes.

I'd like to make my own function here that would replace `fadeOut`. What would my function look like so that this code would work?

```
    $('#current_image').customFadeOut(function(){
        $('#current_image').attr('src',newImage).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is just passing the function reference to the prototypal method you define, and binding that passed function to `$.animate` or whatever jquery animation function you use internally in that.

HTML:

```
<div id="blah" style="color:#fff; opacity:1; background:black; height:50px; position:relative; ">fsdljfdsjfds</div>
<a id="click" href="#">fjsd</a>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.customFadeOut = function (callback) {
    return $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        fontSize: "3em",
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 5000, function () {
        callback.apply(this)
    });

}

$('#click').click(function () {
    $('#blah').customFadeOut(function () {
        alert('hi')

    })

})​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EbRzw/7/)

Comment: Can't "function(){ callback.apply(this); }" be replaced by "callback"?

Comment: Yes, but maybe there needs to be general functionality for all `customFadeOut`s in addition to the `callback` so this way is more flexible yet more explicit. I think a demonstration of more capabilities is better than succinctness. In addition, what if someone calls `customFadeOut` without a function? Then it would fail, and you know how there are a lot of jQuery noobs who don't know JS and/or don't read APIs properly to know you'd have to feed an argument :p